# Django Many-To-Many relationships symmetric different types

Tags: django

In django I have two models `Post` and `Tag`. I have a `ManyToManyField` on each of them refering to the other. However, when I add a new `Post` and supply some tags, only the `post -> tag` relationship is recorded in the database. I have to manully add the `tag -> post` relationship.

Is there a way to get django to do this automatically?

Comment: Why have you defined a many-to-many field on both models? That doesn't sound right. You only need to define it on one (probably the `Post` model) and by definition the relationship goes both ways.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't realize I could query the posts by doing tag.post_set.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also reference using `related_name` in the `ManyToManyField`. It is more cleaner and easier to understand.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="post")
```

then you use it by 
`tag.post.all()`